# Which exception to throw when current state of the object does not allow attempted operation on it?

Tags: c++, error-handling, exception

Let's assume we're implementing a custom collection which behaves like a vector and we want to make `operator[]` throw some exception if collection is empty. `std::vector` has undefined behavior in this case but we want to throw exception. If this was C# we would be probably throwing [`InvalidOperationException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.110).aspx). But which [C++ exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) would be the most appropriate/intuitive in this case? I feel [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) would not be the best choice as collection is empty so there is no 'range' for which indexing would return a valid (*any*) element.

Comment: Actually I think `std::out_of_range` would indeed be the exception I would use. If the container is empty, then any index is out of range, that's the same way that `std::vector` already behaves. Remember an empty set is still a set (in the math sense)

Comment: IMHO I think everyone would understand your usage of `std::out_of_range`.  Even the reference site you link to has *Defines a type of object to be thrown as exception. It reports errors that are consequence of attempt to access elements out of defined range.* which pretty well fits this situation.

Comment: `vector::at` will throw `std::out_of_range` when the vector is empty, so I believe it is indeed the correct exception to use.

Comment: an empty range is still a range, it is just special in that any index is out of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[std::vector::at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) already does this. So you can use `at` method instead of `operator []`. It throws `std::out_of_range` for invalid index.

Please note that you will have to do significant work to achieve the performance of `std::vector`. But still if you want to stick to your own container and want to throw from `[]` then like `at` method `std::out_of_range` is the best choice among standard exception classes. Otherwise you need to define your own custom exception class.

Comment: Thanks @taskinoor. I've been implementing this custom collection just as an exercise...so this was more a hypothetical question. I would definitely avoid doing that in case of commercial/production software unless there was a very good reason to do that.

Comment: @BojanKomazec for learning purpose it is perfectly okay, IMHO. Off topic comment: please have a look at `std::allocator` which you may need to avoid unnecessary calling of default constructors and move semantics which you may need for effective growing operation.